# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

As we enter the second week of the public beta, we desperately need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Patrick McElhaney] [image: Dan Barak]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

A couple more moderators were also added:  [Fresh pro tem moderators, hot off the griddle](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334/fresh-pro-tem-moderators-hot-off-the-griddle)

Comment: Awesome; thanks for volunteering!

Comment: @Robert Fraser I hope you'll be electable in a few weeks. I'd vote for you ;)

Comment: This is cool. I hope to make some time and dedicate a bit more on building on this community. Good Luck!

Comment: @Jouke van der Maas -- Thanks; right back at ya!