# Fresh pro tem moderators, hot off the griddle

Tags: discussion, moderators

As the UX beta progresses, we've seen the need for a couple more [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) to give the existing crew a hand. I'm pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Rahul] [image: Vitaly Mijiritsky]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

Comment: Great news! Rahul and Vitaly, thanks for your hard work and many insightful contributions. Both excellent choices as moderators. I'm glad to have you on board!

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick, I'm very glad to be joining the team! :)

Comment: I hope being a moderator will force me to come back to the site more often. I was slacking too much. ;-)

Comment: @Rahul: I hope so too ;-)

Comment: Congrats and good luck!